# How can I get just one column from a table?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-lightswitch

i have a table named "table_1" which contains id, col_1, col_2, col_3. col_1 is the summary property, so, when i query "table_1" (by any filter), i get the query result summarized by the summary property "col_1".

I need to get the same result but summarized by "col_2" that isn't the summary property. Can anyone help me?

Here's my query code:

```
partial void table_1_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<table_1Item> query)
{
    query = (from item in query
    select item.col_2).Execute().Distinct();
}
```

It doesn't work because it throw me an exception like this:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable in
>   System.Linq.IQueryable"

`col_2` is a string type. So i need that the query result type is `System.Linq.IQueryable<table_1Item>`.

Comment: you want the result in querylist? or simple list?

Comment: I want the result as IQueryable<table_1Item>

Comment: check the updated ans

Comment: same error or something else?

Comment: you are passing the value of query by reference I need change it to by value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
partial void table_1_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<table_1Item> query)
    {
        query = (from item in query
                 select item.col_2).Execute().Distinct();
    }
```

to

```
partial void table_1_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<table_1Item> query)
    {
        query = (IQueryable<table_1Item>)(from item in query
                 select item.col_2).Execute().Distinct();
    }
```

This will cast explicitly.